# Pycharm with no save functions?

Tags: pycharm

I'm using pycharm for school and for some reason I don't have any way to save my project whatsoever. I only have the option to export but that doesn't work at all for my professor.

I used the file function to check and she even tried to show me but I don't have that 'save as' function. Is it something wrong with how I downloaded it?
Please help.

Comment: What do you mean for "save a project"? Give us concrete example. Do your class uses PyCharm? So, ask other students. Note: PyCharm automatically save sources (and projects, configuration, etc.). It is possible that your professor want a specific format, and so you should do it (possibly manually: it is better to do manually: you can do a final check!). Maybe a git repository? Or a zip file? Or a tar? If you navigate in your source, and with right button on mouse, you can go where you selected to store the project.